# Is it possible to run win32com script without having microsoft office on the machine

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, pywin32, win32com

I am trying to run a python program which uses some `win32com` functionality in it- It contains work with some of office modules.

My question is: is it possible to run it on machines without `Microsoft Office` installed on them. Is it possible?

If not, There is alternatives to `win32com` for working with office modules without installing `Microsoft office` (In particular `word`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it is not possible to automate Office without an installation of Office present. When you automate Office, it is Office that performs the work. Hence it must be installed.

If you wish to work on Word documents without requiring Office to be installed, you should find a suitable third party module. For instance, [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). This is just one such module, and I am sure there are more. You would be advised to invest a little time evaluating the options before deciding which one to use.

Comment: To be more precise, I'm building an automation to insert a Macro snippet inside word files(.doc, .docm), unfortunately python-docx doesn't support such option. I've spent some time to search for any third-party module to may help me, with no luck though

Comment: I'm pretty sure I answered what you asked.